# Score = Lower bound of Wilson score confidence interval for a Bernoulli parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics

I am looking for a popularity algorithm that calculates based on 'views' and 'likes'.

It seems the answer is to use the **Lower bound of Wilson score confidence interval for a Bernoulli parameter** and the algorithm is provided here:
http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

The algorithm is provided in several forms on that page - mathematical formula, Ruby and SQL.

I need an SQL version, unfortunately the SQL form given on that website is different from the other two versions in that it seems to calculate on both *positive* and *negative* votes, while the Ruby version needs only `pos` number of positive votes and `n` total number of votes.

I am looking for an SQL statement (Postgres compatible) to calculate based on positive votes only, and I will count 'views' as my `n` total number of votes.

(I did think I could treat `positive + negative` as `n` in their SQL, but then I am puzzled by what to do with `SQRT((positive * negative) / (positive + negative) + 0.9604)`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

THe "algorithm" is simply taking the lower bound of the confidence interval of a ratio.

If you have only positive votes, then just use the number of positive votes.  The purpose of what you reference is to balance positive votes, negative votes, and total votes.  You don't need any such balancing, because positive votes = total votes.

If you have the total number of votes and the positive votes, then you can use:

```
SELECT widget_id, ((positive + 1.9208) / (positive + negative) - 
                   1.96 * SQRT((positive * negative) / (positive + negative) + 0.9604) / 
                          (positive + negative)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (positive + negative)) 
       AS ci_lower_bound
FROM (select w.*, (total - positive) as negative
      from widgets w
     )
WHERE positive + negative > 0 
ORDER BY ci_lower_bound DESC;
```

By the way, I'm not sure that the Wilson correction gives any better results than a one standard deviation lower bound for the positive score:

```
SELECT widget_id, positive/total - sqrt(positive*negative/total)/total
```

Comment: I am getting `ERROR:  integer out of range` from the Wilson query

Comment: @Anentropic . . . My guess is that you have some values of positive/total beyond about 50,000.  You should cast them to floats for the calculation.

Comment: ah yes, I think it's in this part `SQRT((positive * negative) /` have to cast to float

Comment: thanks too for the second simpler query, I actually prefer the results from that on my data

Comment: @Anentropic . . . You might be interested in "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".  Page 122 talks specifically about subtracting one standard deviation from a proportion for comparison purposes.

Comment: One last thing... can you shed any light on conceptually what the 'confidence' level means? The article describes it as _"chance that your lower bound is correct"_ but 'correct' seems a misleading word... otherwise why not choose higher confidence to be more correct?

Comment: @Anentropic . . . For that I will refer you to Chapter 3 in the above book.

Comment: The simpler algorithm will score (1,0) as a 1.0 and (10,1) as an 0.82, which is wrong.  The Wilson algo will factor in the small sample size of (1,0), and score (10,1) much higher, even though (1,0) has a "perfect" score.  That's the benefit of the more complicated algorithm compared to the simpler standard deviation one.

Comment: In postgresql I get an error that you cannot take the square root of a negative number. Is "SQRT((positive * negative)" supposed to be "SQRT((positive * abs(negative))"?

Comment: @kristen . . . `negative`  refers to the number of negative votes.  It is not intended to be a negative number.

Comment: That's what I thought but "WHERE positive + negative > 0" implies that negative should be a negative number.

Comment: @kristen . . . That would be clearer if it were `where total > 0`.

Comment: total is always going to be a positive number so that clause is not necessary.